# Generating huge report without loading the server to the limit

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am designing now a system where you can upload backups in the database and at the user request, he should be able to download a digest in form of a zip. The question is the following: how do you process a huge amount of data without loading to the limit the server and the database?

The constraint of the time should not be taken into consideration, since we can notify the user when the digest is ready, the important thing is to balance the load so that server won't spike when such requests are made.

I was thinking about using a elixir process, however there is not an actual way to limit how many resources it will use.

Comment: You can try: https://hexdocs.pm/exq/readme.html
or: https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html

Comment: I managed to gather more information about this topic, I'll post an detailed answer once I start to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Streams to solve your problem? It might help you out.

Here's a possibly helpful article about the subject of streams:
https://www.poeticoding.com/processing-large-csv-files-with-elixir-streams/

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.